# Using Python OpenCV, how to change mouse pointer shape from two long orthogonal lines?

Tags: python, opencv, line, mouse, shapes

I am using the Python OpenCV library.  I am trying to make the mouse pointer shape appears as two long orthogonal lines moving on top of the (csv2.imread) imported image.  I appreciated it if anybody can help me with how to do so.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: sorry, but you cannot do this from opencv / python. there is no way provided to change the mouse cursor at all. if you REALLY need this, use some real GUI toolkit, like QT

Comment: so you wanna mouse cursor moving on the opencv windows(imshow), and during mouse hovering you wanna a reticle kind of shape also moves ?

Comment: I want to have one horizontal line with a length equal to the background image width and a second vertical line with a length equal to the background image height and their intersection is changing with the mouse location.  I hope this is clear, if not please let me know. Thank you very much for your willingness to help.

Comment: def mouse_callback(event, x, y, flags, params):
    global xv , yv
    if event == cv2.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE:
        # horizontal line
        cv2.line(img, (0, y), (img.shape[1], y), (0, 0, 255), 5)
        # vertical line
        cv2.line(img, (x, 0), (x, img.shape[0]), (0, 0, 255), 5)